# A metaphysical study on property, context, advantage and role?

Tags: metaphysics

Well, I understand this study can be too much complicated for daily life matters. However, I think it's worthwhile for technical domain if the definition and relationship among the concepts property, context, advantage and purpose could be given. I don't expect they could cover 100% cases in technical area, a 95% coverage should be perfect and practical.

My humble conclusion is that: a property could be an advantage in a given context. For example, the property of being **super tall (>200cm)** is an advantage in the context of basketball match, but the same property could be a disadvantage in the context of soccer match.

However, it's not necessarily that a 200cm man is good at shooting a basket. Therefore, this advantage does not entail that he should be a good player. Instead, being tall only gives him the potential of being a good player (the role).

Let's consider another case. If somebody (no matter how tall he is) features being good at shooting, then he is definitely a good basketball player and will play a good role of a basketball player.

Last questions: Is my understand correct? I believe they can be improved. Is there any existing research or textbook on this kind of things? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the notion of 'affordances' by J.J. Gibson: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_J._Gibson